# Netbeans 7.2.1, Java reflection, method.invoke(super, ..)

Tags: java, reflection, netbeans, super

Why trying to invoke

```
try {
    method.invoke(super, "abc", "def");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // ignore for now
}
```

gives me such an error:

```
'.' expected
```

In Netbeans 7.2.1? After clean&build:

```
Compiling 2 source files to C:\Documents and Settings\u\Moje dokumenty\NetBeansProjects\ServletPlus\build\web\WEB-INF\classes
C:\Documents and Settings\u\Moje dokumenty\NetBeansProjects\ServletPlus\src\java\pl\adrian\servlets\ServletPlus.java:45: error: '.' expected
                    method.invoke(super, "abc", "def");
C:\Documents and Settings\u\Moje dokumenty\NetBeansProjects\ServletPlus\src\java\pl\adrian\servlets\ServletPlus.java:45: error: ')' expected
                    method.invoke(super, "abc", "def");
C:\Documents and Settings\u\Moje dokumenty\NetBeansProjects\ServletPlus\src\java\pl\adrian\servlets\ServletPlus.java:45: error: ';' expected
                    method.invoke(super, "abc", "def");
C:\Documents and Settings\u\Moje dokumenty\NetBeansProjects\ServletPlus\src\java\pl\adrian\servlets\ServletPlus.java:45: error: not a statement
                    method.invoke(super, "abc", "def");
C:\Documents and Settings\u\Moje dokumenty\NetBeansProjects\ServletPlus\src\java\pl\adrian\servlets\ServletPlus.java:45: error: ';' expected
                    method.invoke(super, "abc", "def");
5 errors
C:\Documents and Settings\u\Moje dokumenty\NetBeansProjects\ServletPlus\nbproject\build-impl.xml:851: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Documents and Settings\u\Moje dokumenty\NetBeansProjects\ServletPlus\nbproject\build-impl.xml:284: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Comment: Compilation failed in `ServletPlus.java`, line 45

Comment: Hi,@Adrian Adamczyk you asked this question http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51231/andengine-box2d-high-speed-body-overlapping-prismatic-joints?rq=1 (How you drawn the path please please help me)

Comment: @Bashir I've used a lot of TexuredPolygon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my bad understanding of polymorphism, well, it's a bit pitful, because I thought that "super" refers to superclass' object, and "this" to current object - something like that.

Of course, there's only one object which is instanced out of extending class.
So I had to replace "super" with "this".

Answer (score 3):

`super` is a [reserved word in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html).

Try changing the variable name.

See here how you can use the `super` keyword. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

If you want to [invoke a superclass method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896504/java-inheritance-calling-superclass-method) you have to use `super.methodName()`

Comment: There was fault in logic of method.invoke, usage: method.invoke(this, "abc", "def");  solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I belive you are not doin it right : fyi example of how to invoke a method using java reflection :

```
java.lang.reflect.Method method;

try {
  method = obj.getClass().getMethod(methodName, param1.class, param2.class, ..);
} catch (SecurityException e) {
  // ...
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
  // ...
}

try {
    method.invoke(obj, arg1, arg2,...);
}
```

**EDIT:**

And also as @MaVRoSCyhas mentioned `super` is a key word in java

Answer (score 0):

Replace <classInstance> with the name of your class.

```
Method m = <classInstance>.getClass().getSuperClass().getDeclaredMethod("ABC");
m.invoke(<classInstance>);
```