# Parent class reference pointing to Child class Object. Call only parent class method (JAVA)

Tags: java, inheritance

I Have Parent Child relationship class and one override method i want to display only parent class method.

```
class Parent{
    public void display(){
        System.out.println("Parent class display....");
    }
}
class Child extends Parent{
    public void display(){
        System.out.println("Child class display....");
    }
}

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String... args)  {
        Parent parent = new Child();
        parent.display();
    }
}
```

Desired Output :- Parent class display....

Is this Possible ?

Comment: better add to the tags which program language do you need this to work....

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896504/java-inheritance-calling-superclass-method

Comment: Directly you cannot call Parent method, as you are referring to Child object. But, you may print "Parent class Display...." by calling super.display()

Answer (score 1):

Directly, no. To give access to the superclass implementation, you have to expose it somehow, otherwise it it is not visible externally at all. There are a couple ways you can do this.

**Child Method Calling Super**

You could add a method to `Child` that calls `Parent`'s implementation of `display()`:

```
public void superDisplay()
{
    super.display();
}
```

You would have to cast your reference to make the call:

```
((Child)parent).superDisplay();
```

Note that adding a method to `Parent` that calls `display()` would not help because it would call `Child.display()` for `Child` instances because of polymorphism.

Something similar to this technique is commonly used when extending swing components, where the child's implementation of `paintComponent()` often invokes `super.paintComponent()`.

**Reflection**

While often a kludge indicating bad design, reflection will give you exactly what you want. Simply get the `display` method of the `Parent` class and invoke it on a `Child` instance:

```
try {
    Parent.class.getMethod("display").invoke(parent);
} catch(SecurityException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | ex) {
    // oops!
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are simply looking for a way, you can declare your `display()` method to be `static` in both classes.

```
public static void display(){
}
```

Comment: With 99% certainty, that will not help the OP.

Comment: Thnx I got my solution.