# Polymorphism instead of over-riding method, adding on

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

I was wondering. When I have two classes while the second class `metalRobot` extends the first class `robot` is there a way of calling the method of the first class inside of the second method which does override it?

**Example**

```
//super class
class robot{
   private int width;
   private int height;

   //constructor
   robot(int width,int height){
    this.width=height;
    this.width=height;
   }

   //display width and height
   void render()
   {
     System.out.println(width + " " + height);
   }

}


//child class
class metalRobot{
   private int x;
   private int y;

   //constructor
   metalRobot(int x,int y, int height, int width){
    super(width,height);
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
   }

   @Override
   void render()
   {
     System.out.println(x + " " + y);
   }

}
```

so when i call render, it will print out x,y width and height

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Inheritance - calling superclass method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896504/java-inheritance-calling-superclass-method)

Comment: Your `metalRobot` needs to extend the `robot`-class, else it's not a child-class.

Comment: Class names in Java, by convention, should use UpperCase.

Comment: When I was teaching, I told my students I usually got suspicious when I saw an overriding method that didn’t contain a `super` call, as in `super.render();`.

Answer (score 3):

Call super.render() on the first line of render() in metalRobot.

Additional info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Answer (score 2):

First of you need to inherit from `robot`:

```
class metalRobot extends robot {
}
```

Then you can access the parent method by the keyword `super` as:

```
@Override
void render() {
    super.render();
    System.out.println(width + " " + height);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `super.render()` is one solution. Another solution, and one that I personally prefer, is to use [the decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). It requires an additional interface but it gives the user of your class more control over how they compose a composite object.

```
interface Robot
{
    void render();
}

class DefaultRobot implements Robot
{
    public void render()
    {
        //do some stuff
    }
}

class MetalRobot implements Robot
{
    private final Robot wrapped;

    public MetalRobot(Robot robot)
    {
        this.wrapped = robot;
    }

    public void render()
    {
        wrapped.render();
        // do some extra stuff
    }
}
```

Example usage may be something like:

```
Robot robot = new MetalRobot(new DefaultRobot());
```

Say you were to add a `FatRobot` and a `RedRobot` later on you could do:

```
// metal, fat, red robot
Robot robot = new MetalRobot(new FatRobot(new RedRobot(new DefaultRobot())));

// fat and red robot
Robot robot2 = new FatRobot(new RedRobot(new DefaultRobot()));

// red, metal robot
Robot robot3 = new RedRobot(new MetalRobot(new DefaultRobot()));
```

Or any other combination you can imagine. Polymorphism does **not** allow you to do this in an elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call the overriden method of your super class you must use the `super`

keyword follow by a dot then the method name.

e.g. `super.render()`

Note that the `super` is only allowed in a non static method of the sub class.

You can also use the `super` in your constructor when you have a constructor in the

parent class that is not a default constructor you must provide the needed

arguments in your superclass constructor through your subclass constructor

e.g. If your super class has a constructor of `MySuperclass(String myString)`

and does not contain default constructor,

you must provide values for your superclass constructor to do this you use the `super` keyword

```
MySubclass()
{
   super("Needed String");
}
```

also note that multiple inheritance is not allowed in java so you cannot `extends` multiple times e.g. 2 times or more

**Why?**

because the child class doesn't know which `super` is which and many other reasons that is why **James Gosling** doesn't allow this

Answer (score 0):

use *super.render()* to access the method of parent class