# Java Single Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

The child class and parent class has the same function quality() but the functions contain a different set of code. What I've been trying to do is invoke quality() in the parent class and then the quality() of the child class only by using the object of the child class. Is it possible? If yes, could you please explain?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Inheritance - calling superclass method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896504/java-inheritance-calling-superclass-method)

Comment: When defining the child class' method, call the parent's version using super.quality().

Answer (score 1):

You can use `super` if you want to call the parent method.

Something like this:

```
public class Parent {

    protected void foo(){
        System.out.println("1");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{

    @Override
    protected void foo() {
        System.out.println("2");
    }

    void bar() {
        super.foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible using super keyword. 
Inside quality() of child class make a call super.quality() as first statement

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is you need to create your parent class, give it the quality method and let your child/subclasses inherit this. In order to do that you call super() in this constructor, what this does is that it calls its parent class. It knows what your parent is because in the class name you type extends *parent class name*, here ill show you a quick demo!

```
public class A {

    private static B b = new B(); //create class object so I can run it in main
                                //static object as im calling it from a static function

    public int quality(){ //quality method //int method because im returning answer which is an integer
        int answer = 1+1; //random code
        return answer;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){

        System.out.println(b.quality());
    }
}
```

```
public class B extends A { //extends calls the super class

    public B(){ //constructor (super() goes here)
        super(); //invoke parent class
    }

    @Override
    public int quality(){
        int answer = 2+2; //modify the code in this class by overriding it
        return answer;
    }
}
```

output = 4

any questions, ask! Im glad to help :)